# Use algebra to eliminate y from the equations.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ideals

This is the problem. (From Ideals, Varieties, and Algorithms)

Consider the equations \begin{align} x^2 + y^2 -1 = 0 \\ xy -1 = 0 \end{align} which descirbe the intersection of a circle and a hyperbola.

Use algebra to eliminate $y$ from the equations.

Why does it say the intersection of a circle and hyperbola if those two never intersect in $\mathbb{R}$?

What does it mean to eliminate $y$. Do I solve for $x$ for both equations?

I would appreciate as little of an answer and more of a hint.

Thank you.

Comment: I was thinking about that. Am I supposed to consider just one equation at that point? Also $x^2 + (\dfrac{1}{x})^2 - 1 =0$ have no real solutions?

Answer (score 1):

Since abstract algebra and ideals were in the tags I permit myself to introduce you to a bit of theory (the way I see things). Let's starts with the polynomial ring $\Bbb{C}[x,y]$ and the ideal generated by $x^2 + y^2 -1$ and $ xy -1 $. It can be proven that every polynomial that is zero on the intersections of these curves belongs to this ideal and conversely every polynomial in this ideal is zero on the intersection points. To solve such system of equations there is a device called [Gröbner basis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gr%C3%B6bner_basis). I used a C.A.S to calculate a Gröbner basis for this ideal and the result was this system: 
$$\begin{align}  x^2+y^2-1\\ xy-1\\ -y^3-x+y\\ -y^4+y^2-1 \end{align}$$
As you see the last equation doesn't contain $x$ (but I presume that must be satisfactory). Solving this last equation gives values that you can use to solve values for $y$. Substituting these values in the third equation gives you solutions for $x$. I presume that the third equation was obtained by multiplying the first equation with $y$ and the second with $x$ and taking the difference. Then the last equation was obtained by multiplying the third equation with $y$ and subtracting the second equation. I hope this was the answer you were looking for. For more complicated systems the algorithm is way more elaborate, but reading the theory about how Gröbner basis are calculated should be revealing.